# How to give permission to rename a database sql-server

Tags: sql-server, database, rename, database-permissions

I have a user who needs to rename a database.  I could give dbcreator privileges, but this would allow the user to rename any database, and even create new ones.

So I tried to create a stored procedure that the user would call to do the job.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SPMyRenameDB
WITH EXECUTE AS 'MySuperUser'  -- MySuperUser is a SQL user with dbcreator permission
AS
ALTER DATABASE A MODIFY NAME = B
GO
```

I get an error :
The server principal "MySuperUser" is not able to access the database "A" under the current security context.

I tried with sp_renamedb, I get : User does not have permission to perform this action.

Even a simple SELECT statement to a table in database A is not allowed : The server principal "MySuperUser" is not able to access the database "A" under the current security context.

When I connect as MySuperUser and query the database A, it works as expected.  (MySuperUser is a SQL user with dbCreator and sysAdmin privileges on the server).

I suspect that the "WITH EXECUTE AS" statement has some security restrictions that do not allow to use it outside of the current database.

The Stored Procedure is in a database (other than A and B) where the user has db_owner permissions.

Any suggestions ?  I do not need to stick with my "WITH EXECUTE AS" approach.  Anything that would do the trick is welcome.

Thanks,

Yves

Answer (score 1):

Check ALTER DATABASE in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174269.aspx) -> Permissions

> Requires ALTER permission on the database.

So just query as following

```
USE A
GO
GRANT ALTER TO 'someuser'
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

User must be member of dbcreator server role. (MSDN documentation is wrong!).